# Add .last class to last UL and LI inside a UL

Tags: jquery

I have a list which has nested lists inside, to an infinite level.

So the HTML looks like:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item"> 
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"> 
                <a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item"> 
                <a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> 
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"> 
                <a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item"> <!-- This should have the class .last -->
                <a href="#">Last Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The last '`li`' in the nested '`ul`' should have a class of '.`last`' added to it.

My current jQuery is as follows:

```
$('ul.list-group li:last-child').addClass('last');
```

However this is to wide ranging and catches the last '`li`' in each '`ul`' rather than the last '`li`' to occur.

Could I loop through each '`ul`' in some way to detect a counter greater than 1, struggling to think of the correct logic to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/) to get the last element *in the set* :

```
$('ul.list-group li').last().addClass('last');
```

If what you want is to target only nested ul li, use

```
$('ul.list-group ul.list-group li').last().addClass('last');
```

Comment: @prash I'm not sure as the question is very vague to me

Comment: Apologies for the vague question, mid-dev and the list's not fully populated. Probably jumping the gun trying to add this class at this stage. However .last is now my friend so thanks @dystroy

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

```
$('.list-group-item:last').addClass('last');
```